# TideSDK: Python unicode error when launching an app

Tags: tidesdk

I'm having troubles with launching an app on TideSDK, I'm getting this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've got no clue what causes this, since the application was working fine until I put another folder on its 'Resources'. I looked for unusual file names on the folder, but everything seems fine.

Anyone got a clue? :(